# eslint 2.x and babel-eslint Doesn't Recognize Decorators

Tags: babeljs, eslint

I'm trying to upgrade to `eslint` 2.x and the latest version of `babel-eslint`. I've been unable to get decorators or class properties to properly lint. I've created a minimal repro shown below:

`test.js`

```
import {decorator} from 'foo';

@decorator('test')
export class Test {
  testProperty = 'a string';
}
```

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "test.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-eslint": "^6.0.4",
    "babel-plugin-transform-decorators-legacy": "^1.3.4",
    "babel-preset-es2017": "^1.4.0",
    "babel-preset-stage-1": "^6.5.0",
    "eslint": "^2.10.1"
  }
}
```

`.babelrc`

```
{
  "presets": ["es2017", "stage-1"],
  "plugins": ["transform-decorators-legacy"]
}
```

`.eslintrc.json`
{
  "parser": "babel-eslint",
  "parserOptions": {
    "sourceType": "module"
  },
  "rules": {
    "strict": 0
  }
}

When I run `eslint test.js` I get the following:

```
  3:1  error  Parsing error: Unexpected character '@'

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

If I comment out line 3, then I get this:

```
  5:16  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token =

✖ 1 problem (1 error, 0 warnings)
```

It seems that babel-eslint is being used to parse the file, but isn't picking up any information from the `.babelrc` file.

How do I go about enabling eslint and babel-eslint to successfully parse and then lint this file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a bug in the library.

It is recommended to downgrade to version `2.9`.

[GitHub issue](https://github.com/eslint/eslint/issues/6197)

Comment: No need to downgrade, this has been fixed in 2.10.2 AFAIK.